# Mathematical models of learning

Tags: learning, mathematical-psychology, reinforcement-learning, perceptual-learning

Looking for a list of the most common mathematical models of learning. In particular, I am interested in models that explain behavior such as "learning by doing" or "learning from others".

Comment: Hi @mrb, welcome at CogSci. This is potentially very nice question, but could you please specify your question a little bit more, because it is rather broad at the moment. Moreover, could you provide any initial research you have done, and what research you are doing it for. The more context you provide, the better we'll be able to answer it. Moreover, it is nice to get to know our new users ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your nice welcome. I am an economist and I am trying to make sense of a large dataset of adults learning new skills from direct experience, problem-solving, social interaction, and observation. In economics, much of the literature is focused on firms --- not directly on people --- and "steals" from papers in psychology that are 50 or more years old. I was wondering if some  model has emerged over the years offering a more comprehensive view on learning. A sort of "gold standard" that can be used to showcase different theories.

Comment: I don't have the time to give you a full answer, but my answer on [this](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/14064/what-is-the-act-r-model-of-learning/14068#14068) question may give a nice start. Declarative (factual) memory, is predominantly explained by reinforcement learning, and procedural (skill-based) memory is regulated by reward and utility (Q-based learning I guess). Hope it'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: PS. If you could add the additional info in your question, other people may put it in context more easily